# Facebook Login in .net MVC

Tags: .net, facebook, model-view-controller

When I am try to login in my .NET MVC website using Facebook it shows warning:
Submit for Login Review Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook.

Failed to retrieve email address information

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Login fail with facebook... because Failed to retrieve email address information

Comment: You need to go read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Facebook api requires permissions declaration during the request. You need to specify proper ones. Please check link below. Hope will help.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions